# Authenticating to feeds with Nuget from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

Have tried all the six methods in this [link](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/package/get-started/nuget/auth) to authenticate to nuget from visual studio and none of them are of help.

One of my friends has used credential provider earlier.
Now none of them seems to work.

Has anything changed recently with the authentication?

Comment: Which VS version and Nuget version did you use?

Answer (score 0):

I use the easy way with the VSTS:

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/package/get-started/nuget/publish

And then I use another VS2015 with update 3 machine to connect to it, I could get the authentication.

[image]
[image]